# Eliminate spacing between Android Imageview elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a simple grid of images attached next to each other but can't seem to get rid of the ~5px spacing that automatically occurs between each element.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Johan

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
        android:layout_marginRight="0px"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >
<ImageView   
  android:id="@+id/o1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
  android:layout_marginRight="0px"
  android:src="@drawable/p1
<ImageView   
  android:id="@+id/o2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/o1"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
  android:layout_marginRight="0px"
  android:src="@drawable/p2"/>
<ImageView   
  android:id="@+id/o3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@id/o2"
  android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
  android:layout_marginRight="0px"
  android:src="@drawable/p3"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try using a LinearLayout (seems more fit for the job) ?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I'm going to add a second row of images later on, can I do that with a linear layout?

Comment: And linear layout came with the same type of margin/padding between each imageview element :(

Comment: You could either put several horizontal linear layouts in a vertical linear layout, or use a TableLayout ( http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html ), or maybe use a GridView. RelativeLayout doesn't seem fit for that task. Are your drawable plain images ?

Comment: yes they are plain png images with a click event attached

Comment: The problem wasn't some kind of spacing/padding, it was the fact that I had a limeted height on the objects and a fill_parent/wrap_content issue, will try to specify that question in a new post. Thanks for trying to help me!

Answer (score 1):

I found that when using the Android Studio built in import of Drawable resources, it was adding a border around my images, I assume to make them square.  Also, in my case my images wheren't large enough.  My understanding is Android will automatically scale down but not up.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:padding="0px"` to each element.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, did unfortunately not solve the problem, still same spacing between the elements :(

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/01" to the second image.  Do the same for the 3rd image.  It's a relative layout, so you can do this.

Comment: thanks for reply, I did that in the code above but still get a spacing between the elements (allthough they are to the right of each other)

Comment: Are you positive there is no transparent padding on the image itself?  I am not aware of built in padding in this circumstance.

Comment: it was actually the height of the total widget that was spooking on me, and I came to a slightly different challenge with the "fill_parent" issue which I posted as a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6640833/linear-layout-of-several-images-cant-get-fill-parent-wrap-content-right, thanks for helping out though!

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your Image View to remove the blank spacing.